# C++ how to convert single line vector of strings to an integer array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I'm still new to C++ im trying to convert a vector I have made from a .txt file to an array that is of type int.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class LineCounter{
public:
    bool iterateFile(string fileName, function<void(const string&)> callback)
    {
        // Open the File
        ifstream in(fileName.c_str());
        string str;
        // Read the next line from File until it reaches the end.
        while (getline(in, str))
        {
            if (str.size() > 0)
                // Call the given callback
                callback(str);
        }
        //Close The File
        in.close();
        return true;
    }
    int vectorMake()
    {
        vector<string> vecOfStr;
        //Call given lambda function for each line in file
        bool res = iterateFile("input-a1q1.txt", [&](const string& str) {
            // Add to vector
            vecOfStr.push_back(str);
            });
        if (res)
        {
            vecOfStr.erase(vecOfStr.begin(), vecOfStr.begin()+3);
            cout << vecOfStr[0] << endl;
            //NEED TO CONVERT TO INT
            }
        return 0;
        }
};
```

The code I have so far successfully grabs all of the data from the text file and puts it into a vector. It then removes the lines I don't need. I'm stuck trying to change it to int values though as I will need to sort the data into ascending order later on as well as calculate the number of values in the array.

Comment: Use [std::stoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [from_chars](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) standard library function, to convert string into integer.

For example:

```
#include <charconv>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> src = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7"};
    std::vector<int> dst;
    for(auto s: src) {
         int i;
         std::from_chars(s.data(), s.data()+s.size() , i);
         dst.emplace_back( i );
    }

    for(auto i: dst) {
        std::cout << i << ",";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't seem to get from_chars working. I have #include <charconv> but the error "namespace std has no member from_chars

Comment: It needs C++ 17, if you are using GCC or Clang add  [-std=c++17](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options) command line option to your compiler. If you are using Visual Studio use [/std:c++latest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=vs-2019)  in you solution settings. If you have to use some old compiler, without C++ 17 support - you can use [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) instead of from_chars